# Are there any good tools to collect Objective-C metrics?

Tags: objective-c, ios, metrics, code-metrics

I'm using Jenkins for CI on iOS projects and want to collect some software metrics on them. But the only tool I was able to find was [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) which only counts lines of codes (LOCs). Nevertheless it's better than nothing.

What I really want to count are methods, classes, calls to other classes etc. (to do the fancy cyclomatic complexity stuff).

Perhaps I'm missing some tools, let me know, if I do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[OCLint](http://oclint.org/)?

From oclint.org:

> OCLint is a static code analysis tool for improving quality and
>   reducing defects by inspecting C, C++ and Objective-C code and looking
>   for potential problems like:
>
> - Possible bugs - empty if/else/try/catch/finally statements
> - Unused code
>     unused local variables and parameters
> - Complicated code - high cyclomatic complexity, NPath complexity and high NCSS
> - Redundant code -
>     redundant if statement and useless parentheses
> - Code smells - long
>     method and long parameter list
> - Bad practices - inverted logic and
>     parameter reassignment ...

Comment: OCLint is outputing: _This binary is no longer under maintenance by OCLint team. Please consider using xcpretty (https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty) instead!_

Comment: @Cœur I'm also facing the same issue. Do you have any update on this?

Comment: @Akshay I simply use Lizard.

Answer (score 5):

Lizard will do it. Check it out at https://github.com/terryyin/lizard.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [XClarify](http://www.codergears.com/xclarify), a pretty complete objective-c code analyzer, and it's free for [open source contributors](http://www.codergears.com/xclarify/XClarifyForOSS).

Answer (score 2):

Beyond lines of code and test coverage, I'm not sure there are any such tools yet for Obj-C. I suspect we'll see some soon given the influx of devs from other platforms who use metrics, but in my 7 years as an Obj-C dev I haven't heard of anyone having a tool for collecting them. Of course it'd be good to be proved wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

[ProjectCodeMeter](http://www.ProjectCodeMeter.com) measures flow complexity (similar to McCabe cyclomatic complexity) on Objective-C code, but it doesn't count methods and classes though..

Comment: I don't see a Mac version, looks like windows only.

Answer (score 1):

I use few tools for gathering code quality metrics:

- OCLint - Gather some metrics, like cyclomatic complexity, and enforce best practice - http://oclint.org
- Simian - Similarity Analyser -  http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/
- Clang analyzer - Same tool as in Xcode (Product -> Analyze), seems like a bit outdated though useful too. To perform it on CI see that: http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build.html
- Coveralls - nice tools for visualization of unit test coverage - https://coveralls.io

I've found recently that it exists free plugin for SonarQube - https://github.com/octo-technology/sonar-objective-c but it's not really feature-rich. Official one is here: http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/objective-c/

Answer (score 0):

> What I really want to count are methods, classes

nnnot rrreallly.... you can parse the xcode indexes or the output of `nm` -- or run doxygen.

> calls to other classes etc

`gcov` -- or run doxygen

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon [Xcode Statistician](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/freestuff/)  (link seems to be dead), but haven't tried it yet. The [zip archive](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/freestuff/XcodeStatistician.zip) can be downloaded directly.

Comment: I just tried it. Fairly basic stats: LOC per source file, classes, etc. However, no cyclomatic complexity, no methods per class, or any of the more truly useful stats. More disappointingly, it doesn't automatically traverse subfolders. Although the doc refers to scanning your project, it only works on the source files in the current folder.

Comment: That link is broken now.

Comment: @CarlosMacasaet Yeah, looks like it. But you can still download the zip archive via: http://www.literatureandlatte.com/freestuff/XcodeStatistician.zip